# Paging Results .net and the grid concept

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, paging

I´ve been checking .net available paging options (telerik, others) and one recurrent situation that I found is the grid concept to refer to that functionality. By grid concept I mean, columns and rows (even including column name) giving less design customization possibilities.

Does anyone know any implementation or library for .net mvc in order to deploy paging results using more fancy design implementations not attached to column display idea.
brgds, sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure I follow what your trying to do..but for paging data in a grid/column type layout I recommend the jQuery Datatables plugin. Its very customizable/flexible. its allows for styling via css and handles paging, filtering, and sorting among other features.

you can learn more about the plugin [HERE](http://www.datatables.net/)

and [THIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/01/19/jquery-datatables-plugin-meets-c.aspx) is a great article explaining "server-side processing" with asp.net MVC using the plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: uauu great!, I will check that page for jquery. eg for limited design options I refer to this grid format http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/headerfootertemplates . I like very much telerik but I cannot create a beautiful paging result set.

Comment: yep i think jQuery + Datatables is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I continued working in options for paging results - custom design - in asp.net mvc.

Two options are the best:
First one: mvccontrib has a paging option without the need to use a grid view. for code you can check in the following url: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

Second One: Martijn customization of scottgu pagedlist: http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/02/11/mvc-pager-update/

hope it helps!